# JavaScript using Try Catch or If Else for performance

Tags: javascript, if-statement, try-catch

I am experimenting with deep object trees of data and now I would like my code factoring now.

Many times I have to check if a whole branch exists to set or unset a value in. I'm using a lot of 'if else' conditions and I'm thinking of using functions for that.

For instance, to set a value as false in a branch, I could have two solutions like :

```
function setFalse(root, /* [names]* */) { ...
    // If root exists, call setFalse() with the rest of arguments.
    // Else if I only have two arguments : root[arguments[1]] = false ;
    // Else return.
... }
```

Or with try-catch :

```
function setFalse(root, /* [names]* */) {
    try {
        var l = arguments.length,
            branch = root ;
        for (var i=1 ; i<l-1 ; i++) // Not taking the last argument.
            branch = branch[arguments[i]] ;
        branch[arguments[l-1]] = false ; // With last argument.
    }
    catch(e) {}
}
```

The first method is cleaner than the second, but it uses recursivity so it could be heavy.
The second method is a bit dirty (I think) however it might be lighter to execute ?

I have to precise that I don't care if the whole branch exists or not, I just want it to put false if it exists.

Generally I have 4-branch deep objects, but it could be more.
Which method do you think is the most efficient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. The first one is inefficient because it will create a lot of arrays to handle the parameters, and the second one is inefficient because error handling is generally an expensive way to do flow control.

Use the second principle, but check if the property exists for each level, instead of relying on error handling:

```
function setFalse(root /* ,[names] */) {
  var l = arguments.length, branch = root;
  for (var i = 1 ; i < l-1 ; i++) {
    if (!branch.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) return;
    branch = branch[arguments[i]];
  }
  if (branch.hasOwnProperty(arguments[l-1])) {
    branch[arguments[l-1]] = false;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/j6BXc/

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your answer. I wasn't far from the correct method finally.